# Forcing a Region Code format in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I have the following problem, I have a number in one column formatted as 2.60 which is being converted to the format of 2,6 when the region code is changed to "German (Germany)" in Windows. I need this number to retain its original formatting, 2.60. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated, I've searched all over and have come up with nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you find an answer useful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark to its left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose a **specific separator in Excel** (if you don't want it to depends on Windows settings):

#### In Office 2007

- open the Excel Options window
- select "Extended" (*Erweitert* in a German version)
- at the bottom of the first group, choose "Edit options" (*Optionen bearbeiten*)
- there is a checkbox to override the default decimal separator

#### In Office 2003

- go to Menu > Tools > Options
- choose International
- you can choose the Excel decimal separator

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the cell's `NumberFormat` property to `"0.00"`

Comment: The number format has been set to this by default, however if you change global region settings to a non English (United States) format, you may encounter format such as 0,00. I checked my format using the following macro
msgbox(selection.NumberFormat) and it showed 0.00